# how to open specific tcp port on ubuntu

Tags: networking, ubuntu

I am on Ubuntu 18.04, I am trying to run
`python -m http.server 8080`
and everything works, I can connect to the server from other computers
but if I change the port to:
`python -m http.server 8501`
I cannot connect to the server...

I tried `ufw` to allow port 8501, does not work
I tried the `netstat` and it says the system is listen on `0.0.0.0:8501`
I tried `iptables` didn't find anything suspicious...

```
9    ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:8501
10   ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:8501
```

I was able to curl 127.0.0.1:8501 locally.

any particular setting that disallow this port to be accessible to external??

Comment: what error do you get when you fail to connect? is it ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED? and congrats for having checked everything I'd have you check on initial eval, and writing it up concisely (especially checking your listening port status with netstat).

Comment: Yep, it is ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: could it be that my company's internal network configuration disabled the port sharing for any traffic using the port? I just dont know if technically that is possible

Comment: maybe the ports on your system are open but that doesn't mean the ports are open every were else. when this is an companies intranet then you should speak with your companies IT. We can't and will not help there.

Comment: understood, just want to confirm if that is possible, thanks for confirming that @suleiman

Answer (score 0):

It could be that my company's intranet disables the port within the LAN. Although I cannot confirm this easily but if technically possible this could be the reason.